Unable to Update Data in ScyllaDB
I'm encountering an issue while attempting to update data in ScyllaDB using Go. Below is the code snippet I'm using for updating a session record:
func (q *Queries) EndSession(Sessionid string) error {
    tableName := fmt.Sprintf("%s.session", q.keyspace)
    uuid, _ := gocql.ParseUUID(Sessionid)
    stmt := qb.Update(tableName).
        SetLit("logout_at", time.Now().Format(time.RFC3339)).
        SetLit("is_logout", strconv.FormatBool(true)).
        Where(qb.Eq("session_id")).Query(q.session)
    stmt.BindMap(qb.M{"session_id": uuid})

    if err := stmt.ExecRelease(); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}

I logged the bug and got
"message": "line 1:43 : Syntax error",
I think i can't bind data into "session_id" field
